# When using multicast, all users have same bandwidth?

Tags: multicast, bandwidth

I'm reading https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/9370130 and in this paper, achievable rate for the uplink transmission from user n to the UAV is

> [image]

w_n is the bandwidth allocated to user n(users have all different bandwidth). But this is the unicast case.

What I curious about is that when using multicast protocol, do all users have same bandwidth?

Comment: `when using multicast protocol, do all users have same bandwidth?` is a bit confusing. the  type of traffic has nothing to do with the bandwidth, or link capacity, of various endpoints. in terms of multicast, the communication is basically mirrored out at some point to subscribing endpoints. mirrored as in identical bandwidth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That paper is about a wireless link to a UAV and the achievable link speed in various scenarios. Using multicast on such a link isn't likely.

On a wired network, multicast is forwarded just like broadcast by default. If you configure IGMP snooping, multicast frames are filtered from unsubscribed links, freeing bandwidth for other things. All subscribed links either receive or transmit each multicast packet.

On a wireless network like IEEE 802.11 aka Wi-Fi, multicasts are distributed just like broadcasts. Unless you configure otherwise, broadcasts and multicasts use the lowest link speed to enable reception on every node. This uses much more air time than you might expect.